# Does erasing and repulling a master branch affect my other branches

Tags: windows, git, github, terminal

Currently I have two branches:

1. master
2. dev

I'm working with a program and a newer version of it released on github. In order to update, I've been given these commands to put in the terminal: [commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gAux.png)

Currently, my master branch is outdated as I have all of my work on the dev branch. Since the commands require me to

> make clean

my master branch, will this affect my dev branch? I want to save a current version of my code before updating so that I have something to fall back to in case the newer version doesn't work out for me. Or is there another way to save my current code before erasing and repulling my master branch?

Comment: Does `git stash` help your case? Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't delete the `.git` folder, (or do some other operation like outright deleting a local branch), your other branches (locally) are unaffected.

However, it's good practice to push all your branches since you could potentially lose work from something like a harddrive failure or something else.